# Signed JNLP results in more security dialogs

Tags: java, security, jnlp, java-web-start, signed

I have an Eclipse RCP application that is deployed via WebStart. We have not been signing our top level JNLP and as a result launching the client results in the following dialog with the yellow warning icons.

[image]

I found a posting about adding the JNLP to the main jar as JNLP-INF/APPLICATION.JNLP. Then when the main jar is signed, the JNLP will be "signed" and the warnings on the launch dialog will be changed to informational.

[image]

However, when I make this change to my main jar and launch the application, my users are prompted to run the application dialog shown above twice.  JNLP file that is in the top level application directory and in the main jarJNLP-INF/APPLICATION.JNLP file has:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://local.mycompany.COM/Client" href="client.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>Client</title>
    <vendor>mycompany</vendor>
    <description>Client Application</description>
    <shortcut>
        <desktop/>
    </shortcut>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<update check="always" policy="always"/>
<resources>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar"/>
    <extension name="Wrapper feature" href="features/com.mycompany.client.feature_0.7.0.jnlp" />
    <property name="osgi.instance.area" value="@user.home"/> 
    <property name="osgi.configuration.area" value="@none"/> 
    <property name="osgi.configuration.cascaded" value="false"/> 
    <property name="osgi.bundles" value="org.eclipse.equinox.event@2:start,org.eclipse.equinox.ds@2:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@4:start,org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start"/>
    <property name="eclipse.application" value="com.mycompany.client.application"/> 
    <!-- Valid log levels are INFO, WARNING, ERROR -->
    <property name="logLevel" value="ERROR"/> 
    <property name="logFile" value="client.log"/> 
</resources>
<resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <j2se version="1.6+" />
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WebStartMain">
    <argument>-nosplash</argument>
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Has anyone else seen this?  Can someone please tell me what I've done wrong.

Comment: Is that JNLP incomplete? Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: JNLP is complete, missing the 4 spaces before the </jnlp> so it was not appearing.  JaNeLA shows this JNLP is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are prompted to run the application dialog twice because you use an extension:

I guess the first dialog you are prompted asks to run application, the second  - to install extension. It's normal behavior.